# Do i need to explicitly add foreign key to models in has_and_belongs_to_many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have 2 models:

```
class Supplier < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :accounts
end
```

and

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :suppliers
end
```

I made a join table also

```
class CreateJoinTableAccountSupplier < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :Accounts, :Suppliers do |t|
      t.index [:account_id, :supplier_id]
      t.index [:supplier_id, :account_id]
    end
  end
```

My question is do I need to explicitly add foreign keys(supplier_id to Account and account_id to Supplier) to get this work?

When go to console and want to add some accounts for suppliers a got an error:

> ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute
> `id`)

**I tried this in 2 ways:**

s1 = Supplier.new

s1.name = "Marc"

s1.save

a1 = Account.new

a1.name = "marc2"

a1.save

s1.account_ids = 1

**and**

s1 = Supplier.new

s1.name = "Marc"

s1.accounts.create(name: "marc2")

***In both cases I got same error from top***

Comment: As noted by Igor Galvão the error is most likely has nothing to do with the join table and it seems that your `suppliers` and `accounts` table do not have a `id` column.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, you don't.

In RubyOnRails Guides, ActiveRecord migrations for [creating join tables](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-join-table) show off examples without them and indexes being created in a similar fashion to yours.

That being said, I presume there is a typo on the migration, as Capitalized table names (ie: `:Accounts` and `:Suppliers` won't even complete the migration). See the index name it tries to create:

`CREATE  INDEX  "index_Accounts_Suppliers_on_account_id_and_supplier_id" ON "Accounts_Suppliers"  ("account_id", "supplier_id")` and it becomes clear why it fails.

I didn't see any relevant changes in ActiveRecord changelogs ([5.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md), [5.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md) and [5.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md)), but doing it like:

```
class CreateBaseTables < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :suppliers do |t|
      t.string :name
    end

    create_table :accounts do |t|
      t.string :name
    end

  end
end

class CreateJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_join_table :accounts, :suppliers do |t|
      t.index [:account_id, :supplier_id]
      t.index [:supplier_id, :account_id]
    end
  end
end
```

I can run your example without any issues. So it leads to the question: are your other tables properly defined?